# Android - qualify Sax Handler

Tags: android

Typical SAX Parser - I am building a list out of the endElement. I need to only pull results for a certain region. I'm not sure how I pass a region value to the Handler to qualify my results.

Suggestions?

Thanks

```
@Override
public void endElement(String inUri, String inLocalName, String inQName) throws SAXException 
{
    currentElement = false;

    // Title
    if (inLocalName.equalsIgnoreCase(_nodeMain))
    {
        // Construct a Representative object
        PropertiesCust _custObject = new PropertiesCust(_titleValue, _address1Value, _address2Value);

        cList.add(_custObject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just not pass one in, but have a private variable which holds the region handler for you that you can use inside your method?

Comment: I'm not exactly a Java guy so I'm not sure how to pass it since I'm not accessing the method directly. Just create a constructor and then set a public variable?